# Ninject manual initialization with constructor injection

Tags: ninject

How do I do constructor injection when I'm manually initializing the class?

```
public class ApiKeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private IApiService apiService;

    public ApiKeyHandler(IApiService apiService)
    {
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }
}
```

Initializing:

```
var apiKey = new ApiKeyHandler(/*inject here */);
```

How do I accomplish this? My bindings and everything is already setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
var apiKey = new ApiKeyHandler(kernel.Get<IApiService>());
```

However, why not inject the `ApiKeyHandler` itself?

```
var apiKey = kernel.Get<ApiKeyHandler>();
```

[Here is an article about Ninject](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2011/01/21/ninject-mini-tutorial-part-1/):

You basically want to set this up at the beginning of your code and have it available globally:

```
public IKernel kernel  = new StandardKernel();
```

...

```
kernel.Bind<IApiService>()
      .To<SomeConcreteApiService>();
```

Comment: how do find the `kernel` object?

Comment: @Lolcoder I gave a little bit more of an example below my original answer, however I think you might want to check out some other tutorials to get a stronger understanding.